# Full Entity Process can't apply process slot

Tags: php, linux, performance, apache, mysqli

I have a web site that run on shared hosting so for i have 300 to 400 daily page view. Most of time my site goes down and says that have limited resources.
In my cpanel `Entry Processes` show 20/20 at that time. but will be coming down after some time

I contact with the Hosting Provider and get this replay

> mod_fcgid: can't apply process slot for /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php-fcgi
>
> This clearly shows that the amount of access to your website is high and hence no more process slots can be allotted to a new connection. We have server limitations of 256 worker processes for every three child process. So, if any user exceeds this limit the website page will not be accessible.

my web send email by getting content from Database and sending to user by php

Now i want to ask 2 things

1) is there any way to monitor my web resources and check which query will take more time then expected.

2) what will be suitable for sending email

- fetching email template code from database using php
- fetching email template code from file using php

which one is create less load

Please guide me in right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Do a "top" or "ps" to see what is running.

What web server is PHP running in.

If it is running Apache, decrease MaxClients severely -- say down to 5.  And set MySQL's max_connections to one more than that -- 6.

In your PHP code, connect to MySQL only once per page.

With 400 page views per *day*, you really don't need much in resources.  400 per *minute* would be another matter.